# Symfony Friendly Shopping Cart

Tags: php, symfony1, shopping-cart, symfony-1.4

What options exist for a simple shopping cart system on Symfony? I'm looking for something that will:

1. Provide an interface for tracking items to purchase.
2. Provide shopping cart actions and templates (checkout, view cart, etc.)
3. Support Paypal.
4. Support coupon codes.

Every Symfony specific solution I've found (sfShop, symfony-ecommerce, sfShoppingCart) is out-of-date and not maintained for 1.4. Are there any other Symfony specific solutions?

If there's nothing Symfony specific, what more general systems integrate cleanly with Symfony? I'm looking for something simple. I don't need complete ecommerce solutions that provide a store, keep track of items/inventory etc. as this is only for a small, paid registration portion of a larger site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no cart systems out there that work properly for 1.4 at the time being.

I am currently finishing up a cart system that does exactly what you are looking for.  If you are planning on going the custom route, I may be able to help you along the way.

Good luck.

**Update**

I ended up creating a shopping cart plugin for symfony 1.4 and posted it open source at the symfony plugin repository.

You can get more information [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfCartPlugin).

Frontend Demo [here](http://cart.jgallant.com).

Backend Demo [here](http://cart.jgallant.com/cartadmin).

It is intended to be used by developers who are looking to build an e-commerce solution with symfony.

Also made available on [Git](https://github.com/jongallant/sfCartPlugin) as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. Did you dismiss the option of using a non-Symfony specific solution? If so, why?

Comment: I wanted to build myself a codebase in symfony.  I now have a shopping cart system, that I can manipulate quite quickly as it is mine.  I had tried all kinds of carts, but for this specific system, I wanted to use symfony.  Worked out for me, however, you may want to go another route depending on your timeframe etc.

Comment: Looked pretty good at first but the code isn't symfonyish enough for me. no url_for (breaks when changing routing), HTML code in libs folder, "echo" mixed in with database updates, doesn't use config files, no i18n.